# win32 ResetEvent does not reset manual event

Tags: c++, winapi, events

I have a manual resetevent that is always signalled. It does not reset when I tell it to (and it is created correctly as a manual reset event in CreateEvent). The code that sets the event normally is in an executable that hasn't even started yet.

```
while (1) {
    lStatus = GetObjStatus(m_pObj);
    if (lStatus == ST_UP)
        DoStuff();

    DWORD wait = WaitForSingleObject(handle, 5000);
    if (wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        DWORD d = ResetEvent(handle);
        FTRACE("MainLoop() Wakeup signaled %d", d);
    }
}
```

This code generate millions of traces very fast even though the event is reset but never set.

Comment: Do the traces indicate that `d` is zero or non-zero? Can you post a small repro example - a simple program that creates a manual reset event and runs a cut down version of your loop behaves as expected for me.

Comment: Please provide full code. Do not hide the code that you believe is correct. The problem may well be there.

Comment: You may be creating a manual reset event, but what are you telling `CreateEvent()` to set the event's initial state to?

Comment: @Remy [`ResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685081.aspx) always sets the object's state to the nonsignaled state, regardless of the initial state. However, if the event object already exists, the parameters to `CreateEvent` are ignored.

Comment: @IInspectable: I am aware of that, but if the event is initially signaled but `ResetEvent()` keeps failing for whatever reason, that might explain the OP's symptoms.

Comment: @Remy It would, except the only error mode of `ResetEvent` is, if the parameter is incorrect. This implies one of two scenarios: 1) `WaitForSingleObject` also fails and never returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, or 2) `handle` is not a handle to an event object.

Comment: @IInspectable except if `WaitForSingleObject` never returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, he wouldn't get the trace printed, so your option 2 is possibly worth investigating.

Comment: Stupid question perhaps, but are you _sure_ that `DoStuff` doesn't set the event? And also, are you sure that `handle` is an event and not, say, a mutex?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, the trace prints 1, ResetEvent succeeds according to its return code.

Comment: @llnspectable, sorry, can't post my company's copyrighted software here. The only "missing code" is the DoStuff and I am positive it doesn't ever reference the event handle in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @icabod, I'm sure I know the difference between an Event and Mutex. And I'm positive it is not referenced in the DoStuff since that code doesn't have access to the HANDLE at all.

Comment: This question can be closed. I returned to this code a day later (I forgot I'd posted this) and the ResetEvent was working. The only thing that had changed was I had rebooted the computer I was running it on. Not sure why that mattered.